# I want to run a Google Sheets function on the first Monday of every month

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Sheets functions. How do I run a function only on every first Monday of the month?

```
function HideH() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
    target = ss.getSheetByName('Raspored'),
    hsh = ss.getSheetByName('5. tjedan');
  if (ss.getSheetByName('Ne Dirati')
    .getRange(4, 6)
    .getValue() === 1) {
      target.hideColumns(8);
      hsh.hideSheet();
      var width = 165;
  } else {
    target.showColumns(8);
    hsh.showSheet();
    width = 143
  }
  for (var i = 4; i < 8; i++)
    target.setColumnWidth(i, width);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered to use a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)? :)

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately such a specific time-driven trigger does not exist to run (on the first monday of every month).

Comment: Since more that one user commented, if you don't include @name they will not be notified. For further details see [How do comment arroba replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/289691)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) that runs every day including a comparison of the current day to check if its the first Monday of the month, if it isn't, do nothing, if it is, then do whatever should be done.

- Use JavaScript's `new Date()` to create a date object with the current date.
- Use `getDay()` on the date object to get a serial number representing the day of the week, 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday and so on.
- Use `getDate()` on the date object to get the day of the Month.